# How to remove @strin3http//schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/� received from service bus queue received in python script?

Tags: c#, python, json, azure, serialization

I have set the output of Azure stream analytics job to service bus queue which sends the data in JSON serialized format. When I receive the queue message in python script, along with the data in curly braces, I get @strin3http//schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/� appended in front. I am not able to trim it as the received message is not being recognized as either a string or a message. Because of this I cannot de-serialize the data.

Comment: Have you found any decision?

Comment: This problem persists even to this day. If you use ASA, then peek in the Azure Service Bus Explorer in the portal, using either a topic or a queue, you get the garbage. I don't control what libraries, frameworks, or platforms the client chooses to use -- I'm just sending the message. Telling them to do weird hacks is super tacky.

Answer (score 4):

[This TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34750.integrating-service-bus-stack-with-logic-apps-and-azure-functions.aspx) suggests the following code:

```
// Get indices of actual message
var start = jsonString.IndexOf("{");
var end = jsonString.LastIndexOf("}") + 1;
var length = end - start;

// Get actual message
string cleandJsonString = jsonString.Substring(start, length);
```

Pretty primitive but whatever works I suppose...

Answer (score 3):

The issue was similiar with the SO thread [Interoperability Azure Service Bus Message Queue Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542509/interoperability-azure-service-bus-message-queue-messages).

Per my experience, the data from Azure Stream Analytics to Service Bus was sent via AMQP protocol, but the protocol of receiving the data in Python is HTTP. The excess content was generated by AMQP during transmission.

Assumption that receiving the message via the code below, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues/#receive-messages-from-a-queue. The function `receive_queue_message` with the `False` value of the argument `peek_lock` wrapped the REST API [Receive and Delete Message (Destructive Read)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780770.aspx).

```
msg = bus_service.receive_queue_message('taskqueue', peek_lock=False)
print(msg.body)
```

According to the source code of Azure Service Bus SDK for Python include the functions [`receive_queue_message`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py#L937), [`read_delete_queue_message`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py#L884) and [`_create_message`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/_serialization.py#L59), I think you can directly remove the excess content from the `msg.body` using the string common function [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) or [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. The previous answers are only workarounds and do not fix the root cause of this issue. The problem you are encountering is likely due to your Stream Analytics compatibility level. Compatibility level 1.0 uses an XML serializer producing the XML tag you are seeing. Compatibility level 1.1 "fixes" this issue.

See my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307178/263139.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in a .net solution. I was writing a service which sends data to a queue, and on the other hand, I was writing a service which gets that data from the queue. I've tried to send a JSON, like this:

```
            var documentMessage = new DocumentMessage();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(documentMessage);

            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(json);
            await _client.SendAsync(message);
```

In this second service I was getting the JSON but with this prefix:

> @strin3http//schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�

I solved this problem by add **DataContractJsonSerializer** like that:

```
            var documentMessage = new DocumentMessage();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocumentMessage));

            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(documentMessage , serializer);
            await _client.SendAsync(message);
```

If you want to solve the problem in that way, you will have to add Data Attributes from **System.Runtime.Serialization** to the model:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class DocumentMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Property1 { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Property2 { get; private set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Microsoft.ServiceBus nuget package, replace

```
message.GetBody<Stream>();
```

with

```
message.GetBody<string>();
```