# pythonic way of extracting desired substring from a bigger string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string like this

```
msg = b'@\x06string\x083http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\x9a\x05\x18{"PUID":"9279565","Title":"Risk Manager","Description":"<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,"}\x01'
```

The string `{"PUID":"9279565","Title":"Risk Manager","Description":"<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,"}` is `json parsable`. So I come up with the following code to remove garbage strings from the above `msg`

```
x1 =  msg.split(b'{"',1)[1]
>>> 
>>> x1
b'PUID":"9279565","Title":"Risk Manager","Description":"<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,"}\x01'
x2 = x1[::-1].split(b'}"', 1)[1][::-1]
>>> x2
b'PUID":"9279565","Title":"Risk Manager","Description":"<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,'
>>> final_msg = b'{"%s"}'%x2
>>> final_msg
b'{"PUID":"9279565","Title":"Risk Manager","Description":"<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,"}'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(final_msg)
{'Description': "<strong>Risk Manager </strong><br />\\n<br />\\nLentech, Inc. is currently seekinga Risk Manager inGreenbelt,'", 'Title': 'Risk Manager', "b'PUID": '9279565'}
```

Its a bad way of doing what is required, I would like to know a more optimized way of achieving the result. I think regex can be helpful here but I have a very limited knowledge of regular expressions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Azure Service Bus?

Comment: Yes. you are right :)

Comment: Please always explain your context to prevent [xy problems](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: There is nothing bad with what you are doing, You just got a messy response (probably not intended to be consumed as a json) so you have to deal with messy ways to extract the data you need

Comment: Already asked the problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647351/azure-service-bus-python-client-issue, We have decided to go for the 3rd case, as using HTTP protocol have its own limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
import re
final_msg = re.search("{.*}", msg).group(0)
```

Comment: Just be aware that this won't work with a nested dictionary or with multiple JSON objects in one string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert byte type to string type first

```
msg = str(msg)
```

After which you can write a generator function along with enumeration to pull out the index of the symbol you are searching for

```
def gen_index(a_string):
    for i,symbol in enumerate(a_string):
        if symbol == '{':
            yield i
    for j , symbol in enumerate(a_string):
       if symbol == '}':
           yield j

 >>>a = list(gen_index(msg))  # returns the array
 >>># use array slicing to output to json. We need the first occurance of '{' and the last occurance of '}'
 import json
 json_output = json.loads(msg[a[0]:a[-1]+1])
```

Comment: hopefully it will take care of the edge cases where there is a dictionary inside the json. Might work