# Can't JSON parse message received from Azure Service Bus in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, azure, azureservicebus

This is my JS code to receive a message from Azure Service Bus

```
function receiveMessage(serviceBusTopic, serviceBusSubscriber, callback) {
  serviceBus.receiveSubscriptionMessage(serviceBusTopic, serviceBusSubscriber,
{ isPeekLock: true }, function (error, lockedMessage) {

if (!error) {
  try {
    const receivedMessage = JSON.parse(lockedMessage.body);
    console.log('receivedMessage', receivedMessage);
    if (!_.isEqual(receivedMessage.Type, messageType.USERPROFILES_USER_UPDATED)) {
      return;
    }
    //Message received and locked
    callback(receivedMessage);
    serviceBus.deleteMessage(lockedMessage, function (deleteError) {
      if (!deleteError) {
        // Message deleted
        console.log('message has been deleted.');
      }
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log('Start debugging');
    console.log(lockedMessage.body);
  }
```

When I receive a message it has strange encoding and JSON.parse throws an exception.

The lockedMessage output is:

```
{ body: '@\fbase64Binary\b3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�s\u0002{"Type":"SomeEvent"�\u0001}',
   brokerProperties: 
{ DeliveryCount: 9,
  EnqueuedSequenceNumber: 0,
  EnqueuedTimeUtc: 'Thu, 16 Nov 2017 23:50:16 GMT',
  LockToken: '6e3e311f-0fe9-4366-844d-18046fd000db',
  LockedUntilUtc: 'Fri, 17 Nov 2017 00:10:46 GMT',
  MessageId: 'nil',
  PartitionKey: '1d84084f-65af-4a33-bb30-62d97d85557d',
  SequenceNumber: 61643019899633670,
  SessionId: '1d84084f-65af-4a33-bb30-62d97d85557d',
  State: 'Active',
  TimeToLive: 1566804.069 },
   location: '',
   contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
   customProperties: { 'strict-transport-security': NaN, connection: NaN } }
```

The message is coming from a .NET Core service and that service sends with this code:

```
            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SomeEvent);
            var serviceBusMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
            serviceBusMessage.SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
            topicClient.SendAsync(serviceBusMessage).Wait();
```

Why is Node.js not able to parse the message? Another .NET app can receive the same message without any issues.

Comment: what is the EXACT value of `lockedMessage.body` (it's impossible to read what you've put in the question) - can you show that? is it just text, or is it some type of object?

Comment: updated question with full message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>To avoid this, you need to set `ContentType` to `text/plain` when sending a message from .NET Core service. So it should be something like this:</del>

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SomeEvent);
var serviceBusMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload))
{
    ContentType = "text/plain"
};
serviceBusMessage.SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
topicClient.SendAsync(serviceBusMessage).Wait();
```

In this [article](http://www.bfcamara.com/post/84113031238/send-a-message-to-an-azure-service-bus-queue-with), they explained the problem and the solution for .NET.

### Update:

After some diving, this would not happen to me when I either use .NET Core or .NET to send a message with the standard library [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) whether `ContentType` is specified or not.

This is my C# code to send a message:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://...";
        var client = new TopicClient(connectionString, "MyTopic");
        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DemoMessage() { Title = $"hello core!!! {DateTime.Now}" });
        var serviceBusMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        serviceBusMessage.SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");

        client.SendAsync(serviceBusMessage).Wait();

    }

    private class DemoMessage
    {
        public DemoMessage()
        {
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Node.js code to receive a message:

```
var azure = require('azure');

var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService("Endpoint=sb://...");

serviceBusService.receiveSubscriptionMessage('MyTopic', 'sub1', { isPeekLock: true }, function(error, lockedMessage) {
    if(!error) {

        console.log(lockedMessage);

        serviceBusService.deleteMessage(lockedMessage, function (deleteError){
            if(!deleteError){
                // Message deleted
                console.log('message has been deleted.');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

The `lockedMessage` output is:

[image]

---

This only happens when I use .NET and the SDK [`WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) with this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://...";
        var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "MyTopic");
        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DemoMessage() { Title = $"hello core!!! {DateTime.Now}" });
        var serviceBusMessage = new BrokeredMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
        serviceBusMessage.SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");

        client.Send(serviceBusMessage);

    }

    private class DemoMessage
    {
        public DemoMessage()
        {
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, the `lockedMessage` output is:

[image]

So, I think the message you received is sent from another .NET client and I suggest you clear all messages from the topic before you test it in Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. If you are using Stream Analytics then its compatibility level may be the cause of this issue. Stream Analytics compatibility level 1.0 uses an XML serializer producing the XML tag you are seeing. Compatibility level 1.1 "fixes" this issue.

See my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307178/263139.